# Congestion charge?

Tags: london

I am travelling into London on Saturday afternoon & I will be staying in an area that is within the congestion zone. As it is a weekend I understand that I am exempt for paying. But I will be leaving this area on Monday, so do I have to pay the charge as I am coming out of a zone

Comment: Are you traveling _by car_?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are driving a vehicle within the zone and not taking public transit or a cab (in which case you don't need to pay), [as long as you are out of the congestion zone by 0700 Monday morning](https://tfl.gov.uk/modes/driving/congestion-charge), you will not have to pay.

```
 The Congestion Charge is an £11.50 daily charge for driving a vehicle within 
 the charging zone between 07:00 and 18:00, Monday to Friday.
```